# Span text not changing on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I just got into learning CSS3 and HTML5 and right now I'm trying to get my span text to transition into another color when the mouse hovers over the .link div with the following code. For some reason it is not working, I have tried a couple of things to get it to work but no luck so far.

Can anybody help me fix the issue or point me into the right direction?

Thank you!

--

**HTML**

```
<div id="celebrity-list">
    <header>
        <h2>Celebrities</h2>
    </header>

    <div id="a">
        <span class="letter">A.</span>
        <div class="links">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#celebrity-list > div span.letter{
    position: relative;
    font: 22px Arial;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: color .3s ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: color .3s ease-out;  
    transition: color .3s ease-out; 
}

#celebrity-list > div .links:hover #celebrity-list > div span.letter{
    color: #b43838;
}

#celebrity-list > div .links{
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 342px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-transition: border .3s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: border .3s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: border .3s ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: border .3s ease-out;  
    transition: border .3s ease-out; 
}
```

Comment: It might help if you **actually** add some `:hover` styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, your CSS selectors are incorrect. The x > y selector only selects direct children. Both span.letter and div.links are no direct children of #celebrity-list so will not be selected by these selectors. The ">" may be removed in this situation. Next to that, an ID should always be unique.

This is not working at all:

```
#celebrity-list > div .links:hover #celebrity-list > div span.letter{
    color: #b43838;
}
```

You are trying to select span.letter, as a child of a div, as a direct child of #celebrity-list, as a child of .links:hover, as child of a div, as direct child of #celebrity-list.

If you want to change span.links text color you should put this element *after* the div#links and select it as follows:

```
div.links:hover + span.letter { /* your CSS */ }
```

Another option is to put span.letter inside div.links (as a *direct* child) and use the following selector:

```
div.links:hover > span.letter { /* your CSS */ }
```

If you really want to leave span.letter before div.links in your HTML you should use javascript to accomplish the result wanted.

Answer (score 0):

it is because  div.links  is a sibling of the span.letter

your selector must be a parent of the markup you might want to apply a style.